# How do i select a particular area of image?

Tags: selenium

When trying to select some of the portion of image its working fine when the tag 'Canvas' has been used but same code does not work for the tag 'Img'.
Following code is working fine and selecting some of portion of the image.

```
public void lassoSelection() throws Exception {
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='data visualization']")));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //WebElement window = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='view5740053158935886391_623713095327079356']/div/div[2]/canvas[1]"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(window, 30, 30).clickAndHold().build().perform();   
        action.moveToElement(window, 300, 230).release().build().perform();

        System.out.println(window.getSize());
        log.info("The area has been selected");
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();         
    }
```

But when trying with `'WebElement window = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='view8011599534815475643_6289886944926876675']/div/div[2]/img"));' it doesn't selecting the specific area, giving a size "(961, 890)" and test get successfully executed without an error. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: don't think you can select a part of an image... the browser will attempt click and drag.

Comment: My task is it should drag and then release.

Comment: include the relevant HTML/event listeners.  It could be HTML5 drag/drop which require another method.